# How to create multiple objects using ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to make like 50 small balls and 1 big ball using java.awt. One of my projects issues is to create many of those small balls and I tried to use a constructor to do it.

This is a constructor in class Sec that creates small balls:

```
private Main main;

public Sec(Main main){
    this.main=main;

}
```

And this is from class First that creates big ball:

```
private Main main;

public First(Main main){

    this.main=main;

}
```

And the main class that makes everything work:

```
public class Main extends JPanel {

First f = new First(this);    // first big ball

Sec s1 = new Sec(this);      // first small ball
Sec s2 = new Sec(this);      // second small ball
Sec s3 = new Sec(this);      // etc
  (...)
```

Like You can see above I'm creating each object separately, and I need to make like 50 of them, so I thought using ArrayList would be more efficient. So I tried:

```
ArrayList<Sec> tab = new ArrayList<Sec>();{

   tab.add(object1);   // It displays hint "cannot find symbol"

   }
```

Here is the error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code -       Erroneous tree type: <any>
    at project.Main.<init>(Main.java:22)
    at Project.Main.main(Main.java:117)
```

Comment: There are many errors that can be happening here. Specifically, which one are you experiencing?

Comment: Please edit your question to explain the following: what is "create from constructor"? Do you mean "create inside constructor's code"? Or "create by calling particular constructor"? Also, what will you do with 50 objects? Do you have 50 member variables?

Comment: Where did you create `object1`? What is `object1`? Why are there brackets?

Comment: This program is drawing a balls using java.awt. I had copied only a part of the code, the most important part. I need small 50 balls, and Im creating them by this constructor. And object1 should represent my new small ball. To create a small ball I was using Sec s1 = new Sec(this); and I wanted to get more efficient method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ArrayList<Sec> secs = new ArrayList<Sec>(50); // Declare this as a class field
```

Inside that class' constructor, loop and add new `Sec` instances to each location.

```
public YourClass()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        secs.add(new Sec(...));  //include whatever valid arguments to Sec constructor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to make like 50 of them, so I thought using ArrayList would be more efficient

An ArrayList does not *make* objects, but it can be a useful place to keep them;

```
int NUM_BALLS=50;
ArrayList<Sec> balls = Lists.newArrayListWithCapacity(NUM_BALLS);

for (int i=0 ; i<NUM_BALLS ; i++) {
    balls.add(new Sec(...));

}
```

B.T.W.:  `Sec` is a funny name for an object that is supposed to represent a ball.

Answer (score 0):

I think this,

```
 ArrayList<Sec> tab = new ArrayList<Sec>();
 tab.add(object1);
```

Was supposed to be

```
 tab.add(s1); 
 tab.add(s2); 
 tab.add(s3);
```

Or using the diamond operator `<>` and [`Arrays.asList(T...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) like

```
 List<Sec> tab = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(s1,s2,s3));
```